# I want to generate random month, day, hour, min, sec in python but in this code generating random month is not working. How can I do this?

Tags: datetime, random, python-3.6, python-3.7, python-3.8

```
from datetime import datetime
from random import randrange
from datetime import date
import random
import datetime 

arr=""
def random_date(start,l):
   current = start
   while l >= 0:
      curr = current + datetime.timedelta(month=randrange(12),days=randrange(7),hours=randrange(12),minutes=randrange(60),seconds=randrange(60))
      yield curr
      l-=1

startDate = datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20,13,00,00)

arr=[]
for x in random_date(startDate,10):
  arr.append(x.strftime("%d/%b/%y %H:%M:%S"))

for x in range(0,len(arr)):
   print(arr[x])
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

`month`, `hours`, and `minutes` are not valid parameters to `timedelta`.  You probably want something like the following for a random time in the following year:

```
curr = current + datetime.timedelta(days=randrange(365),seconds=randrange(24*60*60))
```